# Trouble sending correct amount of a token with web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, react

i'm trying to transfer a value of 1 of my erc20 token to my contract. In my front end I am using:

```
tokenContract.methods.approve(contract_addr, 1).send({from: accounts[0]});
```

In my smart contract I am using:

```
tokenContract.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 1);
```

This all works fine, in as much as I get a successful token transfer. The issue is what is being received by the contract is not 1 token, but 0.000000000000000001. My question is what conversions do I have to do to ensure 1 is sent, and where do I do the conversion? Front end, smart contract or both? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: those erc20 contract is being developed by you?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia its my token yes but it inherits everything from erc20, i didnt write any of its functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out both the front end and smart contract represent tokens in wei, so 1 token is 0.000000000000000001. In my front end I changed the 1 to web3.utils.toWei("1", 'ether'); and in my smart contract did 1 * 10 ** 18. This worked perfectly.